# compile a cpp file with multiple different header files

Tags: c++, cmake

I have a single cpp file and multiple hpp files. For each hpp file, I want to create an executable using the same cpp file. The header files have different names. Can I do this in CMake?

So I have

source_1.cpp

header_1.hpp
header_2.hpp
...

and I want to create

executable_1
executable_2
...

Comment: You could use a cascade of macros `#ifdef exe1` and pass different macros as preprocessor options, e.g. for [GCC](https://linux.die.net/man/1/g++) it's `-D`. For `-Dexe1` the first header is included and for `-Dexe2` the second header is included.

Comment: Should there be any difference between the different executables?

Comment: I have 40 different header files and I want to automate it. Each header file is a submission from different people. I am grading their homework

Comment: You could do this with a script.

Comment: Why are they "header" files? Why not have them submit the file with cpp suffix? That way you can just compile it.

Comment: @eerorika I should have done that. But I already got the files.

Comment: You could move each group of headers in a separate folder and use different `-I` setting for each group of headers, `-Istudent125689`

Comment: @ultrafrog how about renaming the files?

Comment: @ThomasSablik I can do this in a bash script. This is my last option. I prefer to do it in cmake so that I can do it in Windows as well

Comment: @eerorika yes, renaming and make a folder for each file will solve my problem. I was expecting that there is a more elegant solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The C++ preprocessor can use macros for `#include`.

That is, you can have something like:

```
#include HEADER_FILE_TO_INCLUDE
```

Then when building the source file you could define the macro on the command-line:

```
g++ -DHEADER_FILE_TO_INCLUDE="\"header_1.hpp\"" source_1.cpp
```

---

To do this with CMake you first of all need multiple executable targets, where you specify the same source file for each target.

Then you can use [`target_compile_definitions`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_compile_definitions.html) to specify the macro and the header file to use.

Something like

```
add_executable(executable_1 source_1.cpp)
target_compile_definitions(executable_1 HEADER_FILE_TO_INCLUDE="header_1.hpp")

add_executable(executable_2 source_1.cpp)
target_compile_definitions(executable_2 HEADER_FILE_TO_INCLUDE="header_2.hpp")
```

If all header files are named `header_X.hpp`, with `X` just being a sequence number, then you could easily create a loop from `1` to the max value of header file numbers.